# No omnicompletion in Vim for python

Tags: autocompletion, plugin-you-complete-me

So I got YouCompleteMe working for python autocompletion. Whenever I use a `.` operator such as:

```
import sys
sys.
```

It shows the correct suggestions. Note that I didn't have to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>.

[image]

But when I type the word 'import', it doesn't show any suggestion.

[image]

I have to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> in order for it to show the correct suggestion. I want it to automatically suggest without me having to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: What's the value of `g:ycm_min_num_of_chars_for_completion` option? (check it by running `let g:ycm_min_num_of_chars_for_completion?`)

Comment: @grodzik The output of that command is 2.